# Generation of self signed certificate creates duplicates in store

Tags: c++, windows, x509, certificate-store

During installation of our application we generate a self-signed certificate. We are using the Crypt API to generate the certificate and to insert them into the store.

The problem is that we are generating duplicates of our certificate when we are reinstalling our applications. And this just makes a mess out of the cert store.

How can I check if the certificate is already in place? Or can I use some option to overwrite existing certificates?

```
hStore = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, NULL, CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG | CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER, L"My");
if (!hStore) {
    return 0;
}
CertAddCertificateContextToStore(hStore, pCertificate, CERT_STORE_ADD_REPLACE_EXISTING, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if your certificates already exist, you probably want to use [`CertEnumSystemStore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376058.aspx) + [`CertFindCertificateInStore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376064.aspx) to dump out all the installed certificates. Then you can query for and test the property that you know is identical (such as the X500 issuer name).

There is a fairly in-depth sample here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382362.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I realized that as we wanted to write the certificates to a file we were much better of not actually inserting them into the store at all.

Therefor I am now generating the certificate in a temporary store.

```
hStore = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_MEMORY, 0, NULL, 0, NULL);
if (!hStore) {
    return 0;
}
```